# Bibliography on the module structure of the Field of Fractions of a DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, modules

In [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302007/r-a-dvr-with-fraction-field-k-what-are-the-r-submodules-of-kn) post on mathoverflow, the OP states that ''It is known that if $R$ is a DVR with fraction field $K$, then the $R$-submodules of $K$ are $0,K,x^nR$, with $n$ any integer and $x$ a generator of the maximal ideal of $R$.

Can somebody please tell me where I can read about this statements. I tried to search for it in the Internet and my school's library but didn't find anything.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It is possible that you won't find this exact statement in any book, because it is in some sense too obvious to state. You can easily try to prove it yourself though, using the fact that any element of $K^*$ has the form $ux^n$ where $u\in R^*$.

Comment: You where right, that was a really short proof. I guess I'm clouded since I've been reading a lot of new information. Thank you for your help.